# Springboot Annotation @Bean use with method arguments

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

So I was looking into the following snippet and got question - How will this Bean be initialized in the Context container ? Is the method called with arguments. Btw, this snippet was present in the AppConfig file. Can someone help me in understanding it ?

```
 @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
                                   @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}") String region) {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, container will try to find `AWSCredentialsProvider` dependency, and pass it as param to `amazonS3Client` method.

Comment: But, you should annotate the `class` containing this method with `@Configuration`.